# Thymeleaf - get dom element attributes

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I create html components with Thymeleaf. Components are declared in separate file:

Declaration of basic button in `buttons.html`

```
<div th:fragment="btn-basic" class="btn btn-basic" th:text="${text}" th:classappend="${class}">
    Button
</div>
```

The idea is to provide some type of tool-set for components. Code for using this component will be:

```
<div th:replace="~{buttons :: btn-basic (text='Button Text', class='button-class')}"></div>
```

It's working well, but I think about case when button need to have attributes like: `onclick="..."` or `data-customAttr="..."` or any other attribute. And here goes the problem:

- How to pass attributes to button?
- One way is to pass it as parameter of fragment, but it's too ugly.
- Is there any way to get attributes of placeholder in fragment? (see example below)

This how I want to call fragment:

```
<div th:replace="~{buttons :: btn-basic (text='Button Text', class='button-class')}" onclick="..." data-customAttr="..."></div>
```

and in `btn-basic` fragment want to get these attributes and attach to it. Something like this:

```
<div th:fragment="btn-basic" class="btn btn-basic" th:text="${text}" th:classappend="${class}" onclick="..." data-customAttr="...">
    Button
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar idea, but the question is, if the customizing of a component is as complex as the result, what is the benefit?

Btw. with the [Thymeleaf Layout Dialect](https://ultraq.github.io/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/) you can do something like this: https://ultraq.github.io/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/Examples.html#reusable-templates, I favor that, instead of the everything-as-parameter approach.